# Trouble using an array from another class

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, call

I am writing a program that is supposed to make a user defined array and then fill it with random variables.

I think I have functioning code for asking the user for the dimensions of the array. It has to be an Int between 5 and 20 and the column size cannot be the same as the row size.

The trouble is when I try to print the zero-filled array. I am having trouble calling the method the array is in from Main().

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int row, column;


    //Ask user for row size
            System.out.println("Enter an integer ROW size from 5 to 20");
            row = keyboard.nextInt();
    //Checks if input is out of bounds
            while(row<5 || row>20){
                System.out.println("You did not enter a valid ROW size. Please try again!");
                row=keyboard.nextInt();}
    //Tells user row size
            System.out.println("ROW size: "+row);       
    //Ask user for column size
            System.out.println("\nEnter and integer COLUMN size from 5 to 20. Must be different from ROW size!");
            column = keyboard.nextInt();
    //Checks if input is out of bounds or repeated 
            while(column==row || column<5 || column>20){
                    System.out.println("You did not enter a valid COLUMN size. Please try again!");
                    column=keyboard.nextInt();}
    //Tells user column size
            System.out.println("COLUMN size: "+column);

            ProcessArray obj = new ProcessArray();
            ProcessArray.obj(firstArray);
                    }   
}


import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProcessArray {

/*Main mainObject = new Main();
mainObject.initializeArray(firstArray); */


private int row, column;
private int firstArray[][], secondArray[][];

ProcessArray(int row, int column){
    this.row=row;
    this.column=column;
    //Set array sizes
    firstArray = new int[row][column];
    secondArray = new int[row][column];
}

//fill first array with zeros
    public int[][] initializeArray(int[][] firstArray, int[][] secondArray){

        Arrays.fill(firstArray, 0);
        Arrays.fill(secondArray, 0);

        System.out.println(firstArray);
        return firstArray;
    }
}
```

I get all sorts of error when I mess around with this last few lines in Main(). Any Idea what I'm doing wrong? Also, any ways to clean up/simplify my code?

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of the fundamentals of object oriented programming. Your Main class should be acting as the driver of the program. If should setup the user input/output and call the functions that perform the logic (in the ProcessArray class). Therefore, you shouldn't be instantiating the Main object in ProcessArray; It should be the other way around...Main instantiates a ProcessArray object in the main(String[] args) driver method.

Comment: Well, the first couple things which jump out at me is that you are trying to call a no-arg constructor you haven't defined, and that you are trying to reference `firstArray` in your `main()` method, when it's not static.

Comment: @DavidJones If you're referencing the commented out code, I was playing around to see if something different would work. I tried to make a ProcessArray object but it says I need to define the constructor ProcessArray. I let it Add Arguments to Match and it fixes it to ProcessArray(column, column) I have no idea what this means

Comment: int[][] is a two-dimensional array, also known as an array of arrays. The first dimension contains int[] objects while the second dimension contains int values. In short, you can't ask *Arrays.fill()* to put the int value zero where Java wants int[].

Comment: @JohnLapinski Yeah that's what I was referring to. I misunderstood the overall scope of your project. Are you just trying to initialize a 2-dimensional array of rowSize x colSize, where rowSize and colSize are inputs from the user?

Comment: @gknicker would I be better off filling it with if-statements?

Comment: I think I'll have to categorize this question as "too broad". It's just that you seem to be unaware of so many basic things in the Java language - variable scoping, constructors, referencing fields in objects, static and non-static methods, access modifiers... It's hard to know where to begin.

Comment: @DavidJones yes but it is just the first part of the program

Comment: @RealSkeptic it's been about 14 months since the last time I was coding. I know I need a review

Comment: Then by all means, do get a review. If you coded in the past, then you may be able to skim through some of it. Maybe [the Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html), maybe your own textbooks, maybe some other site.